# Blender OSC Max 8

Tags: add-on

I am trying to get Max 8 to control Blender. I downloaded AddOSC addon and configured the right port, but there seems to be some ignorance on my behalf about the address. I found a tutorial about using Bespoke(music program) to control Blender and everything went smoothly. But when I wanted to use Max 8 nothing is working. In Bespoke the address is simply bespoke/slider0 for example.
I am pretty sure it should be a straight forward procedure but I am stuck - any help?

Cheers

Comment: This looks well formatted, but I am unfamiliar with the software. Can you add links to their documentation pages?

Comment: I found another addon called nodeOSC and it worked. https://github.com/maybites/blender.NodeOSC. The address is arbitrary and you simply use the python script for the parameter you want to control with OSC into the OSC data path, run the provided python server with dedicated port and bingo.